# Extract column name to vector by calling the column name

Tags: r, dataframe

We have a `data.frame`here:

```
df <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(20),x2=rnorm(20),x3=rnorm(20),x4=rnorm(20),x5=rnorm(20),x6=rnorm(20),x7=rnorm(20),x8=rnorm(20),x9=rnorm(20),x10=rnorm(20),x11=rnorm(20),x12=rnorm(20),x13=c(2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1))
```

I know I can view the column names easily with

```
colnames(df)
[1] "x1"  "x2"  "x3"  "x4"  "x5"  "x6"  "x7"  "x8"  "x9"  "x10" "x11" "x12" "x13"
```

Which prints the line above.

I can also get the name of a single column with `colnames(df[...])`, for an example

```
colnames(df[2])
[1] "x2"
```

I can't seem to figure out how to extract a single column name by calling `colnames()` with the name of the column, like

```
colnames(df$x2)
NULL
```

I bet the solution is ridiculously simple, but I just haven't found any useful information regarding this issue.

Comment: Maybe `colnames(df["x2"])`?

Comment: Exactly. Thank you. I can't understand how I missed that, since I swear I tried that when I tested all possible ways. Most likely I did something wrong... :D

Comment: @nicola provided an useful code, but what's the point to such a question? It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Say, it sounds like "Wha is the name of that guy (column) named "john"?"

Comment: I wish to do exactly what I described. To extract any column name to a vector by calling `colname` with the column name. In all cases I know the columns my data contain, but I might not be aware of their order. Hence the dislike for `colname(df[2])`.

Comment: Why would you want to extract the name of a column you already have the name of? Am I missing something here?

Comment: The point is that I wish to further this idea in to a function that uses column names as titles for plots. This is why I wish to extract individual relevant column names into usable form. I could always construct the vector from string variables by hand, but that would be useless work.

Comment: If you ask rhetorically why this question exists, the answer is just as simple. I needed help for an issue I couldn't handle my self. And all the information I was able to get my hands on proved not to be helpful either because of my lacking skills or because of the general quality of the manual.

Comment: Could you try and add a short sketch of the function you want to write? If not prehaps we could continue this in [the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public) rather than writing lots of comments? SO doesn't appreciate that.

Comment: I think I am able to construct the function without help. That was actually the only thing I needed help with. Thank you all for your comments and I'm sorry I couldn't make any more sense.

Answer (score 12):

Single brackets produce a subset of the data frame with just a single column. The new data frame therefore has a name for its one and only column.

```
> class(df[2])
[1] "data.frame"
> colnames(df[2])
[1] "x2"
```

Double brackets `[[` or dollar `$` extracts *the contents* of a single column, which in your case is a numeric. It therefore doesn't have any column names, because it is not a data frame.

```
> class(df$x2)
[1] "numeric"
```

If you want the name of only the second column you should do

```
> colnames(df)[2]
[1] "x2"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to R, the question of how to automatically extract individual column label in a dataframe may seem daunting.

I know this may seem like an outdated topic, but it's still relevant and important for beginners to understand. Luckily, there is a simple solution to this problem that will make your life a lot easier. By using

`colnames(df)[which(colnames(df) == "x2")]`

you can then write a function to iterate or replace the "x2", for example for plotting purposes.